# Android :RecyclerView working strange in Android 6 and 7 ,working fine in 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

My RecyclerView Working perfectly upto android 5.1.1 as shown us the picture below

[image]

But in Android 6 (both in emulator and device).. it is only showing the first line like picture below.. (but before 2 days it's working perfectly..strange)

It's only show the first row in android 6 and 7

please review my code ..

[image]

> app Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.2.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

> CategoryFragment

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {


    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerCategory;
    private int catID = 2;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public CategoryFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        recyclerCategory = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
        recyclerCategory.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        progressDialog = Utils.generateProgressDialog(getActivity(), false);


        callCategoryApi(catID);



        return v;
    }

    private void callCategoryApi(final int catId) {
        progressDialog.show();
        Log.e("calling", "api cat");
        final CategoryApi categoryApi = ServiceGenerator.createService(CategoryApi.class);
        categoryApi.getCategories(catId).enqueue(new Callback<CategoryResp>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CategoryResp> call, Response<CategoryResp> response) {
                progressDialog.hide();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
                    CategoryResp resp = response.body();
                    categoryList = resp.getData().getCategories();

                    if (categoryList.size() > 0) {
                         recyclerCategory.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4));

                        CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
                        recyclerCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);


                    } else {

                    }


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CategoryResp> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.hide();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

> Adapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> dataList;
    private Context mContext;


    public CategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category> dataList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_category_level_one, null);
         v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_category_level_one, null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


                 Picasso.with(mContext).load(dataList.get(position).getCategoryIcon()).into(holder.imageCategoryItem);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageCategoryItem;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageCategoryItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_category_single_item);
        }
    }
}
```

> Single Item

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_category_single_item"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_category_single_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image_category_single_item"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> Fragment xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue...

Comment: please post ur layout

Comment: both single item layout and fragment layout are added..

Comment: replace your inflater line inside onCreateViewHolder of your adapter by following,  View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_item_category_level_one, parent, false);

Comment: i tried ..no change happen @HAXM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution of my proplem ! .. It's because I am using FrameLayout in Fragments xml .. and I changed it into RelativeLayout.. Now Code Works For all Android Versions

> Fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use match_parent for height for your item view. One item fills whole screen vertically so you don't see another.

In your case  LinearLayout `android:id="@+id/layout_category"`

Comment: I tested it by changed it to "wrap_content" and 100dp ..but cannot resolve issue.. if match_parent is the issue we can scroll the recycler view and find next item.. but in this case no scrolling..